# Optimizing code to search for duplicate records in an XML file

Tags: php, sql, xml

I have an XML file containing inventory, about 20,000 items. The records have a SKU and itemid. I want to search through the XML file and find duplicate SKUs.

XML looks like this

```
<SKUDetails>
 <SKU>AAAAA</SKU>
 <Price currencyID="USD">10</Price>
 <Quantity>4</Quantity>
 <ItemID>11111111</ItemID>
</SKUDetails>
<SKUDetails>
 <SKU>BBBBB</SKU>
 <Price currencyID="USD">10</Price>
 <Quantity>10</Quantity>
 <ItemID>2222222</ItemID>
</SKUDetails>
```

I wrote the following PHP code to process this file. It takes about 500 seconds.
I go through each node in the xml file and add a record to a database for the sku and itemid. If the sku already exists in the database i add a second itemid.

Is there a way to optimize this, or is there another method to do this.

here is the code

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('../_result/'.$_GET["file"].'.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//SKUDetails";
$SKUDetailsNodes = $xpath->query($query);
echo("Total SKUs ".$SKUDetailsNodes->length."<br />\n");

if($SKUDetailsNodes->length > 0) {
 foreach ($SKUDetailsNodes as $node) {
 $query = "//ItemID";
 $ItemIDNodes = $xpath->query($query,$node);
 $ItemID = $ItemIDNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

 $query = "//SKU";
 $SKUNodes = $xpath->query($query,$node);
 $SKU = $SKUNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

 if($SKU != '') {
  $insert_query = "IF NOT EXISTS ".
  "(SELECT * FROM dump_inventory WHERE (sku = '$SKU')) ".
  "INSERT INTO dump_inventory (sku,item1) VALUES ('$SKU',$ItemID) ".
  "ELSE ".
  "UPDATE dump_inventory SET item2 = $ItemID WHERE sku = '$SKU'";

  if(!$insert_exec = sqlsrv_query($conn,$insert_query)) {
   print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What is your goal?  Is your goal to insert a unique set of records for SKU and ItemID into your database table?  Or are you just using the database to do the de-duplication, but end-state is to produce an HTML report, XML file, SQL insert statements, etc??

Answer (score 0):

DITCH THE DATABASE!  That is why it is taking so long.  Just keep the list in memory.  Even 20k items is not that big to keep in a list!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a one to many relationship you probably don;t want to store it in the database the way you are. I would suggest one table of SKUs and one table of items with a foreign key reference to the SKU table.

Also:
I would probably assemble the array of items from the XML and then run one insert statement.  This is likely to be much much faster.